# Azure Module in Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to create a resource group in Azure using Ansible. However i am getting following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task

The error appears to have been in '/home/alam/azure/rg.yml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      ^ here
```

Here is my yml playbook:

```
- name: Test the inventory script  
  hosts: azure   
  connection: local  
  gather_facts: no  
  tasks:  

    - name: "Create a resource group"  
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:   
        location: westus  
        name: Testing  
        state: present  
        tags:   
          delete: never  
          testing: testing
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./ansible/contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py rg.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Ansible to at least version 2.1 (better yet to the latest one). The [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_rm_resourcegroup_module.html) are clear on that requirement:

> **azure_rm_resourcegroup - Manage Azure resource groups.**
>
> New in version 2.1.

If you use an older version, the module name will not be recognised and Ansible will throw an error: "no action detected in task."

Comment: Thanks for reply, upgrading to 2.2 version has solved the above error. However ResourceGroup is not getting created in Azure? Any idea if i am running playbook in a right way?

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it. If you have a new one, please ask a new question and include all the relevant information. I can't help you based on "it doesn't work" comment.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 2.2 has resolved the issue. However to create the resources "hosts" should not be "Azure". Change it to "localhost"

Comment: You have `connection: local` defined in your playbook, so it won't run on any other target. Also, the answer is not entirely true, you can run the module on any host provided it has Python dependencies installed.

Comment: Also, the `azure` and `local` you refer to in the answer are just string literals for hosts groups. Someone else might use `foo` and `bar` instead. Unless you provided the inventory file and specified what each group refers to, this has no value for any other user. Mind: `local` is not synonymous with `localhost`.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. you are right. It should be localhost. It worked with localhost, however when i made the value of hosts as "Azure" it just skips.

Comment: There is nothing about skipping the task in the question and you can have `azure` group containing `127.0.0.1` - it will work properly. You did not even specify that the task was skipped in your comment, but just said "RG was not created". That's why I advised you to ask a new question and provide the necessary information. Had you done so, you would have the problem solved three days ago. But it was your informed decision not to.

Comment: No I have not created a new question. i was just trying to fix it, today early morning when i gave a try it worked. so should i be posting new question now?